# Force.com Migration Tool : Email Templates

Tags: salesforce, force.com

I am looking to retrieve all email templates using Force.com ant migration tool. I believe we can not have bulk retrieve for Email Templates, Reports etc.

Is there any way we can retrieve all email templates in one go without specifying each template name? I believe we can some custom implementation using Metadata API, but wondering if someone has already implemented custom ant task for it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Email Templates, Reports etc. are in folders, so you must provide the `containingFolder` attribute to the `sf:bulkRetrieve` task and you'll get back all the items in that folder. For example:

```
<sf:bulkRetrieve 
    username="${sf.username}" 
    password="${sf.password}" 
    serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" 
    retrieveTarget="retrieveUnpackaged" 
    metadataType="EmailTemplate"
    containingFolder="SalesTemplates"
/>
```

To find the folder names themselves, you can query the `Folder` object and filter on the `Type` column for the metadata type you are interested in. For example:

```
SELECT DeveloperName FROM Folder WHERE Type = 'Email'
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried having the following in your mainfest file.? It should retrieve all the Email Templates:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>EmailTemplate</name>
    </types>
    <version>23.0</version>
</Package>
```

Comment: Thanks pbattisson. I tried it but it just does nothing. It doesn't give any error but just doesn't work.

Comment: In that case, have you actually got the migration tool correctly installed and configured? Can it pull down anything? If not then the error is your end not on the Salesforce side.

Comment: Yes, it can pull custom objects, triggers, apex classes, pages without any issue.

Comment: Very strange, and you are sure that you have someEmail Templates available?(sorry to ask such a silly question, worth a check!) - another option is to connect the org to Eclipse and pull down the templates through that. It basically runs the api in the background.

Comment: Yes, we have many templates available. When I try using Eclipse, it works without issue.

Comment: Copy the emailtemplates part of you eclipse's package.xml into your metadata package mainfest. Should work then. If it doesn't you haven't got the metadata API working properly.

Comment: Thanks, I will do it that way. Basially, I was looking to have some solution to sync templates in bulk mode without specifying individual email template.

Comment: My experience has been that email templates need to be explicitly listed in the package.xml, you can't use a wildcard.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the folder/ template names, you can deploy individually, just not using wildcards.

(You could probably script out the member list and construct a dynamic .xml build file)

```
<types>
  <members>Simple_Survey</members>
  <members>Simple_Survey/Alert_Managers_NPS_Survey_Created</members>
  <name>EmailTemplate</name>
</types>
```